# electrolysis of aqueous zinc nitrate

Tags: electrochemistry

Can anyone explain why in the electrolysis of aqueous solutions such as zinc nitrate, the oxidation  half equation shows hydroxide ions forming oxygen and water -   can this half equation be balanced producing oxygen and hydrogen ions - if not why not?

Comment: Indeed it can. It might even be more appropriate that way.
Also, welcome to Chem.SE.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, why we write $\ce{4OH- -> O2 + 2H2O + 4e-}$ and not $\ce{4H2O -> O2 + 4H+ + 4e-}$?

Indeed, you may find **both** these reactions in the [table of standard electrode potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_%28data_page%29) (at $E^0=+0.401$ and $+1.229$, correspondingly; also, note the reversed direction). In some sense, the second equation may even be considered more appropriate, since $\ce{H+}$ is a more abundant species in the solution than $\ce{OH-}$ (zinc salts would produce slightly acidic solutions due to hydrolysis).

But the first reaction was chosen not without reason. See, when we electrolyze something, it is **anions** that rush to the anode to get oxidized. Water molecules are neutral; electric field would not drag them in either direction. So this might be the reason why the equation is written this way, even if the amount of $\ce{OH-}$ is minuscule and the overall reaction looks more like the second one.

Comment: Thanks for that, but what about   2OH−⟶O2+2H+ 2e−

Comment: That's out of question. There is no such thing as H, to begin with. If you mean $\ce{H2}$, then it is still impossible. You just can't have both oxidation and reduction in one half-reaction.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  The question that is bothering me is a “selective discharge” question .  The example has used aqueous copper sulfate.  They have given the reduction of Cu2+  as one half equation and the oxidation of OH-    as the other.  However the text has written the oxidation half equation as 4OH- →O2  + 2H2O + 4e    My query is can the oxidation equation be written as 
2OH-  →O2   +   2H+    +   4e

Comment: Now you propose a mix between the two. Well, no, nobody writes it this way; it would look kinda unnatural.